# Image processing hand feature identification

Tags: image-processing, opencv, skin

I'm working on a problem (in C++/opencv) in which 4 users need to be distinguished from each other using identity information extracted from skin color and features of the upper hand. However, skin color method (in YCrCb) has a very low reliability because there is not much difference between skin tones. Therefore I'm trying to extract more features from the hands such as darker spots etc. To do this, I calculated the laplacian of the images. results:

```
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/818/afb1.jpg/
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/31/afb2i.jpg/
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/638/afb3.jpg/
```

The first two images are from the same hand/person. The second image is a hand from another person. As you can see, a clear bright spot is visible in the frist two images which represent darker spots of the hand. My idea was to sample the handcontour in small squares and to find for these squares in the other images. Afterwards, we can evaluate which image has the most and highest matches for a given image.

However, I cannot find an algorithm to find matches between a sample image and another image. I tried the cvMatchTemplate() operation (http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/openCVTut6.html#Step%202) and meanShift algorithm but the results of both techniques were really bad.

Can someone give me some tips?

Comment: You already posted a very similar question under another user name. Please edit that question with your new insights, and delete this one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image processing skin color identification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589394/image-processing-skin-color-identification)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tough problem since the hand is such a flexible object. You might have some luck if you solve the hand-pose-estimation problem first. 
Here is a good paper to help you get a handle on the research space:

[Vision-based hand pose estimation: a review](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.76.6351&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Video example with OpenCV implementation:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uETHJQhK144

Once you have an estimate of the hand pose, then you have a basis for isolating and comparing the same region of each hand (just the area between knuckles and wrist, for example). Then you could start applying the generic image matching techniques. Applying the Eigenfaces example ("Eigenhands" in your case) might be your best bet.  Eigenfaces is taught in beginning computer vision courses and tons of info is available online.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I created a handmodel but now I need some filters to extract small unique details from the hands such as darker spots. As I explained in my first post, the laplacian revealed many of these features but I think I need other filters to make these details more visible before I can track them. I have tried the gradient and sobel filters but some tips would be nice. Furthermore, I think I need an algorithm to match these features in other images (e.g. comparing a small sample with a black spot extracted from a hand to other hands). I dont now if there are specific algor.

Comment: Yes, once you have the hand region you want to track *properly registered and transformed* you have a basis for the image matching. Training a Haar classifier is the "right" way, but very difficult. Applying the Eigenfaces example ("Eigenhands" in your case) might be your best bet.  Eigenfaces is taught in beginning computer vision courses and tons of info is available online. If you found my answer helpful, please upvote or accept. :) Thanks